# i want to add css to the active button.. how to add active class in angular

Tags: html, angular6

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="side-nav">
    <button type="button" class="btn  side_btn"  (click)="projects()">
        <i class="fa fa-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p>PROJECTS</p>
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn side_btn side_btn  side_btn_child" (click)="lifecycle()" >
        <i class="fa fa-life-ring" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p>LIFECYCLE</p>
    </button>  

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default side_btn  side_btn_child" (click)="master()" >
        <i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p>MASTER</p>
    </button>
</div>
```

**TS CODE**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../../common/services/auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-side-nav',
    templateUrl: './side-nav.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./side-nav.component.css']
})

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})


export class SideNavComponent implements OnInit {


constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, public auth: AuthService) { }

ngOnInit() {
}

projects(){
    this.router.navigate(['project-management'],{relativeTo: this.route})
}

lifecycle(){
    this.router.navigate(['lifecycle'],{relativeTo: this.route})
}

master(){
    this.router.navigate(['metric-master'],{relativeTo: this.route})
}
}
```

how can I use a directive to add the active class to a button that I have clicked? so that I can add CSS to that button.

I want to make those icons color white(#ffffff) if the button is active.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

Create a directive as shown below where activeLink is a class with desired css:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[nav-link]'
  })
  export class NavigationDir implements OnChanges {

    constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {

    }

    @Input() clickedLinkText:string;

    ngOnChanges(){
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.element.nativeElement,"activeLink");
      if(this.element.nativeElement.innerText.toLowerCase()==this.clickedLinkText){
        this.renderer.addClass(this.element.nativeElement,"activeLink");
      }    
    }
  }
```

Step 2:

Modify your buttons as shown below i.e add nav-link attribute, pass $event in your click handler and set the directive input property

```
<button type="button" class="btn  side_btn"  (click)="YourClickHandler($event) nav-link [clickedLinkText]=selectedAnchorText">
        <i class="fa fa-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p>PROJECTS</p>
    </button>
```

Step 3:

Add a new property in your TS file as shown below:

```
 selectedAnchorText: string;
```

Step 4:

Modify all your OnClickEvent handler as shown below:

```
YourClickHandler(event) {
    this.selectedAnchorText=event.target.innerText.toLowerCase(); 
//Add your route logic below
}
```

**Description**
When you will click the button, its event handler will fire and set the selectedAnchorText property value to the clicked button text or id, whatever suits your need. Setting the selectedAnchorText value will set the directive clickedLinkText input property which in turn will trigger directive ngOnChanges lifecycle hook where you check and append active class to the clicked button.

I know the answer can be much concise and better. Please feel free to improve it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: YourClickHandler(event) {
    this.selectedAnchorText=event.target.innerText.toLowerCase(); 
}  .... In this function, its showing error in innerText(not able to import this).